# Node not able to get its namespace parameters

Tags: ros, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My code looks like:

```
rospy.init_node('images_feeder', anonymous=True)
params = rospy.get_param('~')
```

I'm pretty sure it used to work "before", but now it gives:

```
KeyError: '~'
```

The parameters server seems to be running because I can for example successfully:

```
print rospy.get_param('/rosdistro')
```

(which is indigo by the way). Between "before" and now, I performed several ros (system) packages updates, and maybe changed the way I run things (currently "roscore" in one terminal, "rosrun x y" in another).

Could this be a regression, or is there something more to do, so that the node can "get its namespace" ?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263195/node-not-able-to-get-its-namespace-parameters/) by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that code worked previously? I'm not aware of any recent changes to rospy that would have changed this behavior, but I suppose I could have missed something. Also note that the `KeyError` being thrown is exactly what should happen if the parameter you are trying to get ("~") doesn't exist and you don't provide a default value ([documentation here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#get_param)).

Regardless, there are a variety of functions specifically for getting names from the ROS graph in the [rospy.names module](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rospy/html/rospy.names-module.html). You could instead be using `rospy.get_namespace()` or perhaps `rospy.get_name()` (depending on what you are trying to do). Additionally rospy is slightly different from C++ in that you don't need a "private node handle" to be able to access private parameters. In other words, depending on what you are doing, you might not even need to get the namespace directly. You might be able to use something like `rospy.get_param("~private_param1")`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2017-06-05**:
Actually, despite the wording of the question, I am not trying to get the namespace, but to later do:

```
x = params['x']
y = params['y']
```

My problem was, I was not longer providing these parameters (via command line or launch file). If I provide them, everything is fine.

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2017-06-05**:
So the confusing thing is: if the node does not have any parameter, it will fail on `get_param('~')`. I guess it's an implementation quirk.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-06-05**:
Perhaps you'd actually want [rospy.get_param_names](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#get_param_names)?

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2017-06-06**:
That would have helped me debug the problem, but I really want it the way I wrote it, it's just the error that is confusing.